# Can I set SSRS parameter defaults by solution configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

When developing SSRS reports in Visual Studio, I use solution configurations (Debug/Release) to select whether the report will be deployed to a test server or to production. When developing the report, I set up default values for the report parameters so previewing can be done quickly, but these defaults should not be deployed to production, so at present I must remember to remove the default value from EVERY parameter before deploying when I switch to my "Release" configuration. (Or have to clean that up later within SSRS since redeploying does not modify parameter defaults).

I would hope there is some way to link the parameter defaults to the build configuration so that the step of manually removing all default values could be made unnecessary. Does Visual Studio have a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters are only propagated to the server on the first deployment. Keep the defaults set in your development environment. Once the report is deployed, go to the report server, find the report, open the parameters and remove the defaults. These won't be overwritten by subsequent deployments of the report.

Comment: Right -- I know I can do that. I want to know if it's possible to skip that step with some kind of build configuration-based automation.

Comment: I don't think you can but given doing this would be the same amount of work at editing on the server, I don't see it as an issue

Comment: Well, I expect to use this same solution for years in the future, so it is a matter of solving it once at the solution level instead of modifying the server every time I deploy a new report.